# HOWTO pyJasper Quickstart for Windows

Tags: python, report

Trying to set up pyJasper on Windows-7. I only want access from localhost. Couldn't find much documentation on pyJasper, and what you can find is geared for linux. (pyJasper-httpd.sh in particular).

I have downloaded https://github.com/hudora/pyJasper'>pyJasper, and the Jasper Report Libraries (not sure if these are needed, I think pyJasper might have what it needs already).

Where do I need to go from here to get pdf's straight from python? What steps need to be taken?

Comment: It seems that much of the "server-side" pyJasper happens in Jython, so I think if a reasonable conversion of 'pyJasper-httpd.sh' can be made, we will be close. The only call the REALLY matters from httpd.sh is the final 'java' invocation, but its using sed to build the classpath (and I dont know sed), the rest is just setting relative PATHS for jython and jetty.

Comment: It so happens standard MingW includes bash and sed, so I fired up MSYS and ran the script, and all seems to go well until jython start complaining that it can't find ntpath. I suppose this can be fixed, but that makes me realize this was likely not intended for Windows. Hope Im wrong.

Comment: After enough struggle, this is what I decided: If your serious about JasperReports and you want clean and FLEXIBLE python interfacing, use Jasper-Server and https://launchpad.net/pyjasperclient. Jasper-server has community versions, has more power, and has a windows installer (and others). Pyjasperclient (using SOAP) has a cleaner interface, and doesn't make you build your XML by hand (yuck), you can just pass it lists or tuples! Ive not deployed a working system yet, but I think this is the direction Im going.